# Filter array in swift 4.2

Tags: arrays, swift

[image]

How can I filter array only article data in the separate array?

Comment: You mean you want [to map one array to another](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/3017522-map)?

Comment: You should include the definition of your actual type stored in an Array rather than a screenshot of a JSON that you're representing as a custom type in your code.

Comment: Yes, but only article data map in a separate array.

Comment: So you are saying it would be an array of arrays(articles)? I fail to see how that could be useful to you. If you could tell us what you need it more, maybe there is another way to achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably use flat map for this

```
let articleArray = category_articles.flatMap { $0["article"] }
```

this is of course considering `category_articles` is an array of dictionary

Answer (score 1):

```
let seprate_array = category_articles.map {$0.article}
```

for swift 4.2

```
 let seprate_array = category_articles.flatMap {$0.article}
```

you can get array of articles in `seprate_array` array

> use map function to extract specific field

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
struct Category { 
    let name:String 
    let article:String 
}

let cats = [Category(name: "1", article: "art1"),Category(name: "2", article: "ar2"),Category(name: "3", article: "art3")] 
let arr = cats.map { $0.article }
```